# Can I use a Library that used AndroidX with an android support project?

Tags: android, androidx

I'm trying to integrate a library that built on AndroidX and my current project built on Android support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you can.

But you can the other way! So there should be no reason not to migrate your own project to AndroidX.